# mit-ros-pkg on groovy

Tags: ros, openni, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, this is the error message i got when i rosmake `skeletal_tracker`

```
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation(ros::console::LogLocation*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::console::levels::Level)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::initialize()'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:102: undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation(ros::console::LogLocation*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::console::levels::Level)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:102: undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:102: undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
  CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise<mapping_msgs::PolygonalMap_<std::allocator<void> > >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, bool)':
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:241: undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::advertise(ros::AdvertiseOptions&)'
  CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise<body_msgs::Skeletons_<std::allocator<void> > >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, bool)':
  /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:241: undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::advertise(ros::AdvertiseOptions&)'
  CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:372: undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:373: undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:379: undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:380: undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:438: undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:397: undefined reference to `ros::package::getPath(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:438: undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:438: undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:380: undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:379: undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
  CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:64: undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
  /home/chao/catkin_ws/kinect_demos/mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp:64: undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
```

anyone knows what is the error?

got OpenNI from https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI. Installed with steps in README.

this is my CMakeLists.txt. Referred to http://answers.ros.org/question/56403/how-to-link-openni-library-through-the-cmakeliststxt-file/

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4.6)

include ($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
include ($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/FindPkgConfig.cmake)

set (ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)
rosbuild_init ()
rosbuild_add_boost_directories ()
rosbuild_check_for_sse ()

set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
include_directories (${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

pkg_check_modules (LIBUSB REQUIRED libusb-1.0)
include_directories (${LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories (${LIBUSB_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(/usr/include/ni)

find_package(GLUT)
find_package(OpenGL)

pkg_check_modules (LIBUSB REQUIRED libusb-1.0)
include_directories (${LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories (${LIBUSB_LIBRARY_DIRS})

FIND_PATH(OPEN_NI_INCLUDE "XnOpenNI.h" "OpenNIConfig.h" HINTS "$ENV{OPEN_NI_INCLUDE}" "/usr/include/ni" "/usr/include/openni" "/opt/ros/groovy/include/openni_camera")
FIND_LIBRARY(OPEN_NI_LIBRARY NAMES OpenNI libOpenNI HINTS $ENV{OPEN_NI_LIB} "/usr/lib")
LINK_DIRECTORIES($ENV{OPEN_NI_LIB})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPEN_NI_INCLUDE})
LINK_LIBRARIES(${OPEN_NI_LIBRARY})

rosbuild_add_executable (tracker src/main.cpp src/SceneDrawer.cpp)
target_link_libraries (tracker ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}  ${SSE_FLAGS} ${OPEN_NI_LIBRARIES})
```

and this is my manifest.xml

```
  <package>   
  <description brief="A ROS driver wrapper for user tracking">
 
  </description>

  <author>Garratt Gallagher</author>

  <license>BSD</license>

 
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/skeletal_tracker</url>

  <review status="experimental" notes="beta"/>

 <!--  <depend package="ps_engine"/>-->   
 <depend package="body_msgs"/>

  <platform os="ubuntu" version="12.04"/>   
  <platform os="ubuntu" version="10.10"/>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121141/mit-ros-pkg-on-groovy/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2015-05-28**:
Did you manage to get the MIT KinectDemos working on ROS Indigo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

make sure you add catkin/ROS dependencies to you executable:

```
target_link_libraries(executable ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0